# Create list using .stp template using CSOM

Tags: console-application, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-online

I want to create list using .stp file which is uploaded in to the list template Gallary.

--> I am using Console application to create list in online site.
--> have an any idea how to add list from stp file at online site.

I am not getting custom list using below code.

```
listTemplate = Context.Web.ListTemplates.First(t => t.ListTemplateTypeKind == TemplateID);
```

How should i get .stp list template in context ?

Answer (score -1):

First is just a LINQ query to get the first item.

I assume you are using the Client-Side OM?
Did you have explicitely requested Context.Web.ListTemplates (as in: did you ClientContext.Load(ListTemplates)) ? Otherwise it will not be available.

Try this:

```
 var site = context.Web;
 context.Load(site,s => s.ListTemplates );
 context.ExecuteQuery();

 var listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation
 {
       Title = "<Your Title>",
       Description = "<Your Description>"
 };

 var listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name == "<Your Template Name>");
 listCreationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
 listCreationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

 site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This is working if you are creating list using only OOTB list template.